# Ports in SQL Server 2008 to stablish communication 

Tags: sql-server-2008, communication, port

Is it possible to establish a communication with other application or languages using ports?
  If so What steps are required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most definitely. We have lots of ports here in Massachusetts. Sometimes I take my SQL Server to Gloucester, which happens to be primarily a fishing port. There we meet tourists from Europe, and communication can be established in German, Dutch, or other languages.

Comment: Oops, did I misinterpret your question? Maybe this will help then: http://www.msdev.com/Directory/Description.aspx?eventId=533